# python Selenium getting the values as dataframe

Tags: html, python-3.x, dataframe, selenium

First time working web scrapping with python selenium, Here is the `html` I am working on

```
           <div class="Building-locate-sorting">
            <strong>Building Number:</strong> 2828285<br>
            <strong>Building Name:</strong> Staten<br>
            <strong>Entry Date:</strong> 07/01/2019<br>
            <strong>Exit Date:</strong> 06/30/2022<br>
            <strong>DockingTerm Terms:</strong> 2 Eleveator,$50lat<br>
        </div>
```

and in my code I am pulling the code as

```
location = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//td[contains(@class,'Building-locate-sorting')]")
```

and what I really want is to get the values as dataframe/table format

> ```
> BuildingNO|BuildingName|EntryDate|ExitDate 
>    2828285|Staten      |7/1/2019 | 6/30/2022
> ```

I am stuck as all my output are one long values such as

`( Building Number : 2828285 Building Name : Staten .....)`

Any help I greatly appreciate it.
Thank you

Comment: have you tried if [pandas DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) will work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to scrape table using Pandas from Selenium's result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45394374/trying-to-scrape-table-using-pandas-from-seleniums-result)

Comment: pd.read_html is not really returning anything..