# How to scrape table with flight data, avoiding an empty result?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to extract a table from a webpage and have tried a number of alternatives, but the table always seems to remain empty.

Two of what I thought were the most promising sets of code are attached below. Any means of extracting the data from the webpage would be considered as helpful. I have also included a screenshot of the table I want to extract.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
 
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.set_window_size(1120, 550)
# Create an URL object
url = 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/aircraft/ja11jc'
browser.get(url)
element = WebDriverWait(browser, 3).until(
   EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "tbl-datatable"))
)
data = element.get_attribute('tbl-datatable')
print(data)
browser.quit()
```

or alternatively,

```
# Import libraries
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
 
# Create an URL object
url = 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/aircraft/ja11jc'
# Create object page
page = requests.get(url)
 
# parser-lxml = Change html to Python friendly format
# Obtain page's information
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')
soup
 
# Obtain information from tag <table>
table1 = soup.find("table", id='tbl-datatable')
table1
 
# Obtain every title of columns with tag <th>
headers = []
for i in table1.find_all('th'):
 title = i.text
 headers.append(title)
 
 
 # Create a dataframe
mydata = pd.DataFrame(columns = headers)
 
# Create a for loop to fill mydata
for j in table1.find_all('tr')[1:]:
 row_data = j.find_all('td')
 row = [i.text for i in row_data]
 length = len(mydata)
 mydata.loc[length] = row
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to scrape table using Pandas from Selenium's result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45394374/trying-to-scrape-table-using-pandas-from-seleniums-result)

Comment: Possibly yes, but the answers provided below are much simpler and neater alternatives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Best practice is and first shot scraping table data should go with [`pandas.read_html()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html), it works in most cases, needs adjustments in some cases and only fails in specific ones.*

Issue here is, that a [`user-agent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent) is needed with `requests` to avoid the `403`, so we have to help `pandas` with that:

```
requests.get('http://www.flightradar24.com/data/aircraft/ja11jc', 
        headers={'User-Agent': 'some user agent string'}).text
     )[0]
```

Now the table could be scraped, but have to be transformed a bit, cause that is what the browser will do while rendering - `.dropna(axis=1)` drops columns with NaN values and `[:-1]` slices the last row, that contains non relevant information:

```
requests.get('http://www.flightradar24.com/data/aircraft/ja11jc', 
        headers={'User-Agent': 'some user agent string'}).text
     )[0].dropna(axis=1)[:-1]
```

You could also use `selenium` give it some `time.sleep(3)` while browser renders table in final form and process the `driver.page_source` but in my opinion this is a bit to much, in this case.

##### Example

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

df = pd.read_html(
        requests.get('http://www.flightradar24.com/data/aircraft/ja11jc', 
        headers={'User-Agent': 'some user agent string'}).text
     )[0].dropna(axis=1)[:-1]

df.columns = ['DATE','FROM', 'TO', 'FLIGHT', 'FLIGHT TIME', 'STD', 'ATD', 'STA','STATUS']
df
```

##### Output

|  | DATE | FROM | TO | FLIGHT | FLIGHT TIME | STD | ATD | STA | STATUS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 10 Dec 2022 | Tokunoshima (TKN) | Kagoshima (KOJ) | JL3798 | — | 10:00 | — | 11:10 | Scheduled |
| 1 | 10 Dec 2022 | Amami (ASJ) | Tokunoshima (TKN) | JL3843 | — | 08:55 | — | 09:30 | Scheduled |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 58 | 03 Dec 2022 | Amami (ASJ) | Kagoshima (KOJ) | JL3724 | 0:56 | 01:45 | 02:02 | 02:50 | Landed 02:58 |
| 59 | 03 Dec 2022 | Kagoshima (KOJ) | Amami (ASJ) | JL3725 | 1:06 | 00:00 | 00:09 | 01:15 | Landed 01:14 |

Comment: Simply amazing! Just what I needed. Thanks a lot. I'm quite new to this scraping thing and to python in general. This really helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import requests
import pandas as pd


response = requests.get('https://www.flightradar24.com/data/aircraft/ja11jc', headers={'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
df = pd.read_html(response.text)[0][:-1]
df = df.dropna(axis=1, how='all')
print(df.to_string(index=False))
```

OUTPUT:

```
                JL3798 10 Dec 2022 - Scheduled STD 10:00 ATD — STA 11:10 FROM Tokunoshima (TKN) TO Kagoshima (KOJ)       10 Dec 2022 Tokunoshima (TKN)   Kagoshima (KOJ)            JL3798                 —             10:00                 —             11:10                 Scheduled               Play
                    JL3843 10 Dec 2022 - Scheduled STD 08:55 ATD — STA 09:30 FROM Amami (ASJ) TO Tokunoshima (TKN)       10 Dec 2022       Amami (ASJ) Tokunoshima (TKN)            JL3843                 —             08:55                 —             09:30                 Scheduled               Play
                    JL3844 10 Dec 2022 - Scheduled STD 07:45 ATD — STA 08:15 FROM Tokunoshima (TKN) TO Amami (ASJ)       10 Dec 2022 Tokunoshima (TKN)       Amami (ASJ)            JL3844                 —             07:45                 —             08:15                 Scheduled               Play
                 JL3710 10 Dec 2022 - Scheduled STD 06:45 ATD — STA 07:15 FROM Okierabu (OKE) TO Tokunoshima (TKN)       10 Dec 2022    Okierabu (OKE) Tokunoshima (TKN)            JL3710                 —             06:45                 —             07:15                 Scheduled               Play
     JL3715 10 Dec 2022 - Estimated departure 05:25 STD 05:25 ATD — STA 06:15 FROM Okinawa (OKA) TO Okierabu (OKE)       10 Dec 2022     Okinawa (OKA)    Okierabu (OKE)            JL3715                 —             05:25                 —             06:15 Estimated departure 05:25               Play
                     JL3716 10 Dec 2022 - Scheduled STD 03:55 ATD — STA 04:45 FROM Okierabu (OKE) TO Okinawa (OKA)       10 Dec 2022    Okierabu (OKE)     Okinawa (OKA)            JL3716                 —             03:55                 —             04:45                 Scheduled               Play
                 JL3711 10 Dec 2022 - Scheduled STD 02:55 ATD — STA 03:25 FROM Tokunoshima (TKN) TO Okierabu (OKE)       10 Dec 2022 Tokunoshima (TKN)    Okierabu (OKE)            JL3711                 —             02:55                 —             03:25                 Scheduled               Play
                    JL3841 10 Dec 2022 - Scheduled STD 01:50 ATD — STA 02:25 FROM Amami (ASJ) TO Tokunoshima (TKN)       10 Dec 2022       Amami (ASJ) Tokunoshima (TKN)            JL3841                 —             01:50                 —             02:25                 Scheduled               Play
                    JL3842 10 Dec 2022 - Scheduled STD 00:35 ATD — STA 01:05 FROM Tokunoshima (TKN) TO Amami (ASJ)       10 Dec 2022 Tokunoshima (TKN)       Amami (ASJ)            JL3842                 —             00:35                 —             01:05                 Scheduled               Play
JL3791 09 Dec 2022 - Estimated departure 22:45 STD 22:45 ATD — STA 00:05 FROM Kagoshima (KOJ) TO Tokunoshima (TKN)       09 Dec 2022   Kagoshima (KOJ) Tokunoshima (TKN)            JL3791                 —             22:45                 —             00:05 Estimated departure 22:45               Play
            JL3734 09 Dec 2022 0:57 Landed 09:38 STD 08:40 ATD 08:41 STA 09:45 FROM Amami (ASJ) TO Kagoshima (KOJ)       09 Dec 2022       Amami (ASJ)   Kagoshima (KOJ)            JL3734              0:57             08:40             08:41             09:45              Landed 09:38       KML CSV Play
                JL3836 09 Dec 2022 0:15 Landed 07:52 STD 07:40 ATD 07:37 STA 08:00 FROM Kikai (KKX) TO Amami (ASJ)       09 Dec 2022       Kikai (KKX)       Amami (ASJ)            JL3836              0:15             07:40             07:37             08:00              Landed 07:52       KML CSV Play
                JL3837 09 Dec 2022 0:11 Landed 07:00 STD 06:50 ATD 06:49 STA 07:10 FROM Amami (ASJ) TO Kikai (KKX)       09 Dec 2022       Amami (ASJ)       Kikai (KKX)            JL3837              0:11             06:50             06:49             07:10              Landed 07:00       KML CSV Play
              JL3867 09 Dec 2022 0:46 Landed 05:45 STD 04:50 ATD 04:59 STA 05:50 FROM Okinawa (OKA) TO Amami (ASJ)       09 Dec 2022     Okinawa (OKA)       Amami (ASJ)            JL3867              0:46             04:50             04:59             05:50              Landed 05:45       KML CSV Play
          JL3866 09 Dec 2022 0:30 Landed 04:15 STD 03:25 ATD 03:45 STA 04:10 FROM Yoronjima (RNJ) TO Okinawa (OKA)       09 Dec 2022   Yoronjima (RNJ)     Okinawa (OKA)            JL3866              0:30             03:25             03:45             04:10              Landed 04:15       KML CSV Play
            JL3861 09 Dec 2022 0:35 Landed 02:59 STD 02:10 ATD 02:24 STA 02:55 FROM Amami (ASJ) TO Yoronjima (RNJ)       09 Dec 2022       Amami (ASJ)   Yoronjima (RNJ)            JL3861              0:35             02:10             02:24             02:55              Landed 02:59       KML CSV Play
                        JL3803 09 Dec 2022 - Unknown STD 01:12 ATD 01:12 STA 01:28 FROM Kikai (KKX) TO Amami (ASJ)       09 Dec 2022       Kikai (KKX)       Amami (ASJ)            JL3803                 —             01:12             01:12             01:28                   Unknown       KML CSV Play
          JL3830 09 Dec 2022 - Estimated departure 01:12 STD 01:10 ATD — STA 01:30 FROM Kikai (KKX) TO Amami (ASJ)       09 Dec 2022       Kikai (KKX)       Amami (ASJ)            JL3830                 —             01:10                 —             01:30 Estimated departure 01:12               Play
                JL3831 09 Dec 2022 0:12 Landed 00:30 STD 00:20 ATD 00:18 STA 00:40 FROM Amami (ASJ) TO Kikai (KKX)       09 Dec 2022       Amami (ASJ)       Kikai (KKX)            JL3831              0:12             00:20             00:18             00:40              Landed 00:30       KML CSV Play
            JL3721 08 Dec 2022 0:59 Landed 23:34 STD 22:25 ATD 22:35 STA 23:40 FROM Kagoshima (KOJ) TO Amami (ASJ)       08 Dec 2022   Kagoshima (KOJ)       Amami (ASJ)            JL3721              0:59             22:25             22:35             23:40              Landed 23:34       KML CSV Play
            JL3734 08 Dec 2022 0:55 Landed 09:35 STD 08:40 ATD 08:41 STA 09:45 FROM Amami (ASJ) TO Kagoshima (KOJ)       08 Dec 2022       Amami (ASJ)   Kagoshima (KOJ)            JL3734              0:55             08:40             08:41             09:45              Landed 09:35       KML CSV Play
                JL3836 08 Dec 2022 0:09 Landed 07:51 STD 07:40 ATD 07:42 STA 08:00 FROM Kikai (KKX) TO Amami (ASJ)       08 Dec 2022       Kikai (KKX)       Amami (ASJ)            JL3836              0:09             07:40             07:42             08:00              Landed 07:51       KML CSV Play
                JL3837 08 Dec 2022 0:09 Landed 07:03 STD 06:50 ATD 06:54 STA 07:10 FROM Amami (ASJ) TO Kikai (KKX)       08 Dec 2022       Amami (ASJ)       Kikai (KKX)            JL3837              0:09             06:50             06:54             07:10              Landed 07:03       KML CSV Play
              JL3867 08 Dec 2022 0:48 Landed 05:41 STD 04:50 ATD 04:53 STA 05:50 FROM Okinawa (OKA) TO Amami (ASJ)       08 Dec 2022     Okinawa (OKA)       Amami (ASJ)            JL3867              0:48             04:50             04:53             05:50              Landed 05:41       KML CSV Play
          JL3866 08 Dec 2022 0:25 Landed 04:01 STD 03:25 ATD 03:36 STA 04:10 FROM Yoronjima (RNJ) TO Okinawa (OKA)       08 Dec 2022   Yoronjima (RNJ)     Okinawa (OKA)            JL3866              0:25             03:25             03:36             04:10              Landed 04:01       KML CSV Play
            JL3861 08 Dec 2022 0:32 Landed 02:55 STD 02:10 ATD 02:24 STA 02:55 FROM Amami (ASJ) TO Yoronjima (RNJ)       08 Dec 2022       Amami (ASJ)   Yoronjima (RNJ)            JL3861              0:32             02:10             02:24             02:55              Landed 02:55       KML CSV Play
                JL3830 08 Dec 2022 0:09 Landed 01:20 STD 01:10 ATD 01:11 STA 01:30 FROM Kikai (KKX) TO Amami (ASJ)       08 Dec 2022       Kikai (KKX)       Amami (ASJ)            JL3830              0:09             01:10             01:11             01:30              Landed 01:20       KML CSV Play
                JL3831 08 Dec 2022 0:08 Landed 00:28 STD 00:20 ATD 00:20 STA 00:40 FROM Amami (ASJ) TO Kikai (KKX)       08 Dec 2022       Amami (ASJ)       Kikai (KKX)            JL3831              0:08             00:20             00:20             00:40              Landed 00:28       KML CSV Play
            JL3721 07 Dec 2022 0:57 Landed 23:29 STD 22:25 ATD 22:31 STA 23:40 FROM Kagoshima (KOJ) TO Amami (ASJ)       07 Dec 2022   Kagoshima (KOJ)       Amami (ASJ)            JL3721              0:57             22:25             22:31             23:40              Landed 23:29       KML CSV Play
      JL3772 07 Dec 2022 0:30 Landed 09:32 STD 09:00 ATD 09:02 STA 09:30 FROM Tanegashima (TNE) TO Kagoshima (KOJ)       07 Dec 2022 Tanegashima (TNE)   Kagoshima (KOJ)            JL3772              0:30             09:00             09:02             09:30              Landed 09:32       KML CSV Play
      JL3777 07 Dec 2022 0:27 Landed 08:25 STD 07:50 ATD 07:58 STA 08:30 FROM Kagoshima (KOJ) TO Tanegashima (TNE)       07 Dec 2022   Kagoshima (KOJ) Tanegashima (TNE)            JL3777              0:27             07:50             07:58             08:30              Landed 08:25       KML CSV Play
            JL3784 07 Dec 2022 0:55 Landed 07:13 STD 06:05 ATD 06:18 STA 07:10 FROM Kikai (KKX) TO Kagoshima (KOJ)       07 Dec 2022       Kikai (KKX)   Kagoshima (KOJ)            JL3784              0:55             06:05             06:18             07:10              Landed 07:13       KML CSV Play
            JL3785 07 Dec 2022 1:00 Landed 05:32 STD 04:25 ATD 04:31 STA 05:35 FROM Kagoshima (KOJ) TO Kikai (KKX)       07 Dec 2022   Kagoshima (KOJ)       Kikai (KKX)            JL3785              1:00             04:25             04:31             05:35              Landed 05:32       KML CSV Play
      JL3762 07 Dec 2022 0:26 Landed 03:37 STD 03:10 ATD 03:10 STA 03:45 FROM Tanegashima (TNE) TO Kagoshima (KOJ)       07 Dec 2022 Tanegashima (TNE)   Kagoshima (KOJ)            JL3762              0:26             03:10             03:10             03:45              Landed 03:37       KML CSV Play
      JL3763 07 Dec 2022 0:24 Landed 02:32 STD 02:00 ATD 02:08 STA 02:40 FROM Kagoshima (KOJ) TO Tanegashima (TNE)       07 Dec 2022   Kagoshima (KOJ) Tanegashima (TNE)            JL3763              0:24             02:00             02:08             02:40              Landed 02:32       KML CSV Play
            JL3780 07 Dec 2022 0:51 Landed 01:13 STD 00:15 ATD 00:22 STA 01:20 FROM Kikai (KKX) TO Kagoshima (KOJ)       07 Dec 2022       Kikai (KKX)   Kagoshima (KOJ)            JL3780              0:51             00:15             00:22             01:20              Landed 01:13       KML CSV Play
            JL3783 06 Dec 2022 1:00 Landed 23:45 STD 22:35 ATD 22:45 STA 23:45 FROM Kagoshima (KOJ) TO Kikai (KKX)       06 Dec 2022   Kagoshima (KOJ)       Kikai (KKX)            JL3783              1:00             22:35             22:45             23:45              Landed 23:45       KML CSV Play
      JL3772 06 Dec 2022 0:25 Landed 09:15 STD 09:00 ATD 08:50 STA 09:30 FROM Tanegashima (TNE) TO Kagoshima (KOJ)       06 Dec 2022 Tanegashima (TNE)   Kagoshima (KOJ)            JL3772              0:25             09:00             08:50             09:30              Landed 09:15       KML CSV Play
      JL3777 06 Dec 2022 0:25 Landed 08:15 STD 07:50 ATD 07:50 STA 08:30 FROM Kagoshima (KOJ) TO Tanegashima (TNE)       06 Dec 2022   Kagoshima (KOJ) Tanegashima (TNE)            JL3777              0:25             07:50             07:50             08:30              Landed 08:15       KML CSV Play
            JL3784 06 Dec 2022 0:55 Landed 07:09 STD 06:05 ATD 06:14 STA 07:10 FROM Kikai (KKX) TO Kagoshima (KOJ)       06 Dec 2022       Kikai (KKX)   Kagoshima (KOJ)            JL3784              0:55             06:05             06:14             07:10              Landed 07:09       KML CSV Play
            JL3785 06 Dec 2022 0:59 Landed 05:34 STD 04:25 ATD 04:35 STA 05:35 FROM Kagoshima (KOJ) TO Kikai (KKX)       06 Dec 2022   Kagoshima (KOJ)       Kikai (KKX)            JL3785              0:59             04:25             04:35             05:35              Landed 05:34       KML CSV Play
      JL3762 06 Dec 2022 0:22 Landed 03:48 STD 03:10 ATD 03:26 STA 03:45 FROM Tanegashima (TNE) TO Kagoshima (KOJ)       06 Dec 2022 Tanegashima (TNE)   Kagoshima (KOJ)            JL3762              0:22             03:10             03:26             03:45              Landed 03:48       KML CSV Play
      JL3763 06 Dec 2022 0:24 Landed 02:47 STD 02:00 ATD 02:23 STA 02:40 FROM Kagoshima (KOJ) TO Tanegashima (TNE)       06 Dec 2022   Kagoshima (KOJ) Tanegashima (TNE)            JL3763              0:24             02:00             02:23             02:40              Landed 02:47       KML CSV Play
            JL3780 06 Dec 2022 0:54 Landed 01:38 STD 00:15 ATD 00:44 STA 01:20 FROM Kikai (KKX) TO Kagoshima (KOJ)       06 Dec 2022       Kikai (KKX)   Kagoshima (KOJ)            JL3780              0:54             00:15             00:44             01:20              Landed 01:38       KML CSV Play
            JL3783 05 Dec 2022 1:04 Landed 23:45 STD 22:35 ATD 22:41 STA 23:45 FROM Kagoshima (KOJ) TO Kikai (KKX)       05 Dec 2022   Kagoshima (KOJ)       Kikai (KKX)            JL3783              1:04             22:35             22:41             23:45              Landed 23:45       KML CSV Play
        JL3686 05 Dec 2022 0:53 Landed 12:09 STD 11:10 ATD 11:16 STA 12:10 FROM Matsuyama (MYJ) TO Kagoshima (KOJ)       05 Dec 2022   Matsuyama (MYJ)   Kagoshima (KOJ)            JL3686              0:53             11:10             11:16             12:10              Landed 12:09       KML CSV Play
        JL3687 05 Dec 2022 0:42 Landed 10:44 STD 09:45 ATD 10:02 STA 10:40 FROM Kagoshima (KOJ) TO Matsuyama (MYJ)       05 Dec 2022   Kagoshima (KOJ)   Matsuyama (MYJ)            JL3687              0:42             09:45             10:02             10:40              Landed 10:44       KML CSV Play
         JL3808 05 Dec 2022 1:07 Landed 09:22 STD 07:50 ATD 08:15 STA 09:05 FROM Okierabu (OKE) TO Kagoshima (KOJ)       05 Dec 2022    Okierabu (OKE)   Kagoshima (KOJ)            JL3808              1:07             07:50             08:15             09:05              Landed 09:22       KML CSV Play
         JL3809 05 Dec 2022 1:28 Landed 07:31 STD 05:55 ATD 06:03 STA 07:20 FROM Kagoshima (KOJ) TO Okierabu (OKE)       05 Dec 2022   Kagoshima (KOJ)    Okierabu (OKE)            JL3809              1:28             05:55             06:03             07:20              Landed 07:31       KML CSV Play
                       JL3785 05 Dec 2022 - Canceled STD 04:25 ATD — STA 05:35 FROM Kagoshima (KOJ) TO Kikai (KKX)       05 Dec 2022   Kagoshima (KOJ)       Kikai (KKX)            JL3785                 —             04:25                 —             05:35                  Canceled               Play
      JL3762 05 Dec 2022 0:25 Landed 03:49 STD 03:10 ATD 03:24 STA 03:45 FROM Tanegashima (TNE) TO Kagoshima (KOJ)       05 Dec 2022 Tanegashima (TNE)   Kagoshima (KOJ)            JL3762              0:25             03:10             03:24             03:45              Landed 03:49       KML CSV Play
      JL3763 05 Dec 2022 0:28 Landed 02:48 STD 02:00 ATD 02:20 STA 02:40 FROM Kagoshima (KOJ) TO Tanegashima (TNE)       05 Dec 2022   Kagoshima (KOJ) Tanegashima (TNE)            JL3763              0:28             02:00             02:20             02:40              Landed 02:48       KML CSV Play
            JL3780 05 Dec 2022 0:51 Landed 01:34 STD 00:15 ATD 00:42 STA 01:20 FROM Kikai (KKX) TO Kagoshima (KOJ)       05 Dec 2022       Kikai (KKX)   Kagoshima (KOJ)            JL3780              0:51             00:15             00:42             01:20              Landed 01:34       KML CSV Play
            JL3783 04 Dec 2022 1:03 Landed 23:45 STD 22:35 ATD 22:42 STA 23:45 FROM Kagoshima (KOJ) TO Kikai (KKX)       04 Dec 2022   Kagoshima (KOJ)       Kikai (KKX)            JL3783              1:03             22:35             22:42             23:45              Landed 23:45       KML CSV Play
            JL3464 04 Dec 2022 0:57 Landed 08:10 STD 07:10 ATD 07:13 STA 08:15 FROM Amami (ASJ) TO Kagoshima (KOJ)       04 Dec 2022       Amami (ASJ)   Kagoshima (KOJ)            JL3464              0:57             07:10             07:13             08:15              Landed 08:10       KML CSV Play
            JL3465 04 Dec 2022 1:05 Landed 06:31 STD 05:25 ATD 05:26 STA 06:40 FROM Kagoshima (KOJ) TO Amami (ASJ)       04 Dec 2022   Kagoshima (KOJ)       Amami (ASJ)            JL3465              1:05             05:25             05:26             06:40              Landed 06:31       KML CSV Play
            JL3724 04 Dec 2022 0:53 Landed 02:43 STD 01:45 ATD 01:50 STA 02:50 FROM Amami (ASJ) TO Kagoshima (KOJ)       04 Dec 2022       Amami (ASJ)   Kagoshima (KOJ)            JL3724              0:53             01:45             01:50             02:50              Landed 02:43       KML CSV Play
            JL3725 04 Dec 2022 0:56 Landed 01:02 STD 00:00 ATD 00:05 STA 01:15 FROM Kagoshima (KOJ) TO Amami (ASJ)       04 Dec 2022   Kagoshima (KOJ)       Amami (ASJ)            JL3725              0:56             00:00             00:05             01:15              Landed 01:02       KML CSV Play
            JL3724 03 Dec 2022 0:56 Landed 02:58 STD 01:45 ATD 02:02 STA 02:50 FROM Amami (ASJ) TO Kagoshima (KOJ)       03 Dec 2022       Amami (ASJ)   Kagoshima (KOJ)            JL3724              0:56             01:45             02:02             02:50              Landed 02:58       KML CSV Play
            JL3725 03 Dec 2022 1:06 Landed 01:14 STD 00:00 ATD 00:09 STA 01:15 FROM Kagoshima (KOJ) TO Amami (ASJ)       03 Dec 2022   Kagoshima (KOJ)       Amami (ASJ)            JL3725              1:06             00:00             00:09             01:15              Landed 01:14       KML CSV Play
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. This is a great alternative to what I needed and was provided by HedgeHog above. The answer would have sufficed, but I simply chose the one above based on the fact that the information is needed in tabular form rather than string for further permutations. I'm quite new to this scraping thing and to python in general. This really will be of great help in future work. Thanks.